# How to get ressource ID for a drawable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I use asyncImage from coil and would like to put a ressource to data parameter
with a ressource name as string

Here is my code

```
{
            var resID = mContext.resources.getIdentifier(settFile, "drawable", mContext.packageName)
            val resNoID = mContext.resources.getIdentifier("nomap", "drawable", mContext.packageName)
            if (resID==null) {
                resID=resNoID
            }

            AsyncImage(
                model = resID,
                contentDescription = "This is an image"
            )
        }
```

settFile is a ressourcename string / mContext = LocalContext.current

No error but no image appears

Any help?

Comment: you got image file in resources why don't you use just an Image composable. nevertheless check my answer